# Application joins elasticsearch - does the order of the array of results from the first query influence the scoring the results in the second query?

Tags: elasticsearch

This may sound like a silly question, but I cannot find any information on searching *with* arrays of strings on elasticsearch (rather than searching documents which contain fields of strings), and whether weighting/score calculation is influenced by order. So I was wondering if, when I do an application-side-join will the order of - in this case -  Ids in the array of results from the first query influence the scoring of the results from the second query.

Ex. (ignore syntax)

```
first query results = [6, 3, 9, 7]
second query = 'will have: terms { aFieldInThisDocument: first query results }'
```

Now I'm wondering if that, for example, if two results in the second query both would originally receive a very similar score (and the document with the lower score of the two, matches 'aFieldInThisDocument' with '6')...

-> would the score of the result which matches 'aFieldInThisDocument' with '6' have its score influenced by the fact that the 6 came before all the other results in the array (possibly bumping the score of that result above the score of the other result)?